# Is there any generic way to obtain $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(kn+q)^s}$ from Riemann zeta function?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

Similar concepts could be found here:
[Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function), where Riemann zeta function was of the form $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$.

Is there any generic way to obtain $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(kn+q)^s}$ from Riemann zeta function directly? 
Specifically, how to express $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(kn+1)^s}$ directly as an expression of Riemann zeta function?

Comment: Do you intend that $k$ and $q$ are integers, or can they be more general numbers?

Comment: @EricTowers Right now I only consider integers, but if there's a formula it should work for reals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As EricTowers wrote
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(kn+q)^s}=k^{-s} \,\zeta \left(s,\frac{q}{k}\right)$$
Let $a=\frac{q}{k}$ an expand as a series
$$\zeta (s,a)=a^{-s} +\zeta (s)-a s \zeta (s+1)+\frac{1}{2} a^2 s (s+1) \zeta (s+2)-\frac{1}{6} a^3 s
   (s+1) (s+2) \zeta (s+3)+O\left(a^4\right)$$ that is to say
$$\zeta (s,a)=a^{-s}+s\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{   (s+1)_{n-1} }{n!}\zeta (n+s)\, a^n$$

Answer (score 1):

For $k$ and $q$ real and positive, we should expect
$$  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(kn+q)^s} = \frac{1}{k^s} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\left( n+\frac{q}{k} \right)^s} = \frac{1}{k^s} \zeta(s,q/k)  \text{.}  $$

There's the [multiplication theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Hurwitz_zeta_function).  But this is probably exactly backwards from what you want (it starts with the zeta series, then groups the terms with congruent $n \pmod{k}$).  It is
$$  k^s \zeta(s) = \sum_{q=1}^k \zeta \left(s, \frac{q}{k} \right)  \text{.}  $$

If the relation you want were known, I imagine

Ashton, A.C.L, and A.S. Fokas, "[Relations among the Riemann Zeta and Hurwitz Zeta Functions, as Well as Their Products](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=2ahUKEwjJ4vD1l-HlAhUDITQIHcceCWQQFjAJegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mdpi.com%2F2073-8994%2F11%2F6%2F754%2Fpdf&usg=AOvVaw1EVgk7kCA4f4wmuZFv_7bp)", Symmetry 2019, 11, 754; doi:10.3390/sym11060754

from June of this year would have been much, much shorter.